# C++ Scope Operator in Derivation List

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, nested-class

I'm getting an error in WinImp.h that says `'Root' has not been declared`. If I don't use the scope operator (`class WinImp : public BaseDef`) the error is `error: expected class-name before '{' token`). Anyone know why this is happening?

Root.h

```
class Root {
    public:
        class BaseDef {
            public:
                virtual void foo() = 0;
                virtual void bar() = 0;
        };
    private:
        #ifdef _WIN32
        friend class WinImp;
        #else
        friend class NixImp;
        #endif

        BaseDef* imp;

        BaseDef* getImp();

    public:
        Root() : imp(getImp()) {}
        void foo();
        void bar();
};
```

Root.cpp

```
#include "Root.h"
void Root::foo() {
    imp->foo();
}

void Root::bar() {
    imp->bar();
}
```

WinImp.h

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include "Root.h"
class WinImp : public Root::BaseDef {
    public:
        void foo();
        void bar();
};
#endif
```

WinImp.cpp

```
#include "WinImp.h"
#ifdef _WIN32
    void WinImp::foo() {

    }

    void WinImp::bar() {

    }

    Root::BaseDef* Root::getImp() {
        return static_cast<BaseDef*>(new WinImp());
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Because `BaseDef` has namespace visibility restricted to `Root`. You have to qualify its namespace to gain access to it. Also, you should not need `Root::` in front of your `WinImp::foo()` and `WinImp::bar()` definitions.

Comment: Unrelated: don’t use `dynamic_cast` for up-casts. *Only* use it for downcasts, and even then *only* when you are not sure whether the cast is going to succeed (because the dynamic type isn’t known) and you are actually checking whether the cast’s return value is `!= nullptr`. Upcasts are implicit and downcasts where the dynamic type is known should use `static_cast`.

Comment: @WhozCraig how do I qualify its namespace?

Comment: You're doing it in your code already (the `class WinImp : public Root::BaseDef` is what finds `BaseDef` as a nested class of `Root`). In other words, you actually solved the problem yourself. I stripped down a cut of your post and [put it here](http://ideone.com/GmLj8H) if you want to see it clearer. (your code ma be clouding what you are actually seeing).

Comment: But then I get the error saying `'Root' has not been declared` at that line

Comment: @which line? your question first-paragraph and your actual code body declare `class WinImp` differently (which you need to fix). The question body (`class WinImp : public BaseDef`) is wrong; the one in the code (`class WinImp : public Root::BaseDef `) is right. However, I would advise making those methods in `BaseDef` public, or at least protected.

Comment: When I compile with `class WinImp : public Root::BaseDef` I get `'Root' has not been declared`. When I compile with `class WinImp : public BaseDef` I get `error: expected class-name before '{' token`.

Comment: Ok, that is indeed odd. The sample I linked assumes all your includes are lined up correctly. Can you verify the `Root.h` that you're including in `WinImp.h` (and thereby `WinImp.cpp`) is indeed *the* `Root.h` that has your `class Root` definition? Easy enough. Temporarily stick a `#error RootIncluded` in `Root.h` right before the class decl, then manually compile *only* `WinImp.cpp` if it doesn't break, then somehow you're including the wrong `Root.h`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Now I feel silly. I had two `#include WinImp.h`s in `Root.h`

Comment: @Eliezer dont' feel too bad. and you shouldn't need *any*. the friend decls should be fine without including either WinImp or NixImp formal definitions. Root.cpp on the other hand.. =P. Glad you found it.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing `BaseDef` interfaces in Root, so they suppose to be public:

```
class BaseDef 
{
 public:
   virtual void foo() = 0;
   virtual void bar() = 0;
};
```

In WinImp.cpp, `foo(), bar()` need return type and they are not inside Root scope, should be:

```
void WinImp::foo() { }
void WinImp::bar() { }
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that was me just being lazy. It was correct in my actual code./

Answer (score 2):

Fix `WinImp.cpp` to look like this:

```
#include "WinImp.h"
#ifdef _WIN32
    // WinImp is not scoped within Root
    void WinImp::foo() {

    }

    void WinImp::bar() {

    }

    Root::BaseDef* Root::getImp() {
        return dynamic_cast<BaseDef*>(new WinImp());
    }
#endif
```

Comment: @moswald Thanks, I don't know why I had `WinImp` scoped within `Root`. However, I don't understand why I should scope `getImp()` within `WinImp`. It's a member function of `Root`.

Comment: Oh jeez, I should seriously edit my answer. This is what I get for visiting SO while I've got the flu. For some reason I was thinking `getImp` was virtual.